# Why a state is not resolved as a variable in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js, next.js

I am using passportjs middleware for authentication and it works, but when I'm trying to use the user object in components the property is undefined, although is passed in _app.js.

The app is nextjs based with an express server. I know the user is authenticated because I can trace it in the server, but not in any component.

```js
// _app.js
import React from 'react';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import theme from '../theme/theme';

class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
        let pageProps = {};
        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
        }
        if (ctx.req && ctx.req.session && ctx.req.session.passport) {
            pageProps.user = ctx.req.session.passport.user;
        }
        return { pageProps };
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: props.pageProps.user
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

        const props = {
            ...pageProps,
            user: this.state.user,
        };

        return (
            <Container>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <Component {...props} />
                </ThemeProvider>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Webstorm is pointing at `user: this.state.user` line, complaining unresolved variable `user` but I do not understand why is not resolved as a variable, it is defined in the constructor.

Edit: and this is the server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const next = require("next");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const uid = require('uid-safe');
const authRoutes = require("./auth-routes");
const oAuth2Strategy = require("./lib/passport-oauth2-userinfo");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({
    dev,
});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    const sessionConfig = {
        secret: uid.sync(18),
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 86400 * 1000 // 24 hours in milliseconds
        },
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true
    };
    server.use(session(sessionConfig));

    passport.use(new oAuth2Strategy(
        {
            authorizationURL: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_URL,
            tokenURL: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_TOKEN,
            clientID: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.REACT_APP_CALLBACK,
            userProfileURL: process.env.REACT_APP_OPENID
        },
        function(accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) {
            console.log(profile);
            return done(null, profile);
        }

    ));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user));
    passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user));

    server.use(passport.initialize());
    server.use(passport.session());
    server.use(authRoutes);

    const restrictAccess = (req, res, next) => {
        if (!req.isAuthenticated()) return res.redirect("/login");
        next();
    };

    server.use("/", restrictAccess);
    server.use("/profile", restrictAccess);

    server.get("*", handle);

    http.createServer(server).listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log(`listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
    });
});
```

Edit 2: thanks to @SimplyComplexable I troubleshooted a little bit. In my index.js I can access the user prop like this e.g. `this.props.user.displayName` with no problem.

This works:

```js
import Landing from "./Landing"
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.user.displayName}
                <Landing />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

But, for example, in `Landing` component the prop.user is undefined. Maybe I am not accessing correctly or passing the prop somehow?

```js
class Landing extends React.Component {
    const {user} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            ...
    )
}
export default withStyles(useStyles)(Landing);
```

Comment: Try with "this.props.pageProps.user"

Comment: @liskaandar `this.props` is not available in the constructor.

Comment: is `ctx.req && ctx.req.session && ctx.req.session.passport` really truthy?

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes, it is true and I can see pageProps.user values defined when debugging at that point

Comment: Can you console log `pageProps` in `getInitialProps` and check if the value is actually being set? I suspect what @EmileBergeron is wondering, which is that if statement is evaluating to true so it's never being set.

Comment: Correction "...which is that the if statement isn't evaluating to true so `pageProps.user` is never being set."

Comment: Can you post your server file?

Comment: server file added @SimplyComplexable. Yes,  I can console log `pageProps` in `getInitialProps`, inside the if condition so is evaluated true and `pageProp.user` set.

Comment: I created this code sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-world-gwqob, to try to troubleshoot but it's working without issue. Do you notice any differences with the what I have setup and what you do?

Comment: yes, your code @SimplyComplexable looks the same and works as expected. I tried in my index.js and works, but not in "deeper" components, question edited

Comment: Is `Landing` a page? I updated the code sandbox to show how you would get the prop in a page vs a component. Look at the about page and then the Landing component which is used in the index page.

Comment: @Pere I created an answer. If that worked for you, just make sure to mark it as correct so the question closes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue based on the code you have now, is that you're not passing `user` down to the `Landing` component.
If you update your home page with the following changes, you're code should work.

```
import Landing from "./Landing"
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.user.displayName}
                <Landing user={this.props.user}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

With user specifically this would be a great opportunity for [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), so that you don't have to explicitly pass down the user prop to every component.
Here's a quick example:

```
import Landing from "./Landing"
import React from "react";

export const UserContext = React.createContext({});

class Home extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.user.displayName}
                <UserContext.Provider value={this.props.user}>
                  <Landing user={this.props.user}/>
                </UserContext.Provider>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import UserContext from './Home';

const Landing = () => {
    const user = React.useContext(UserContext);
    return (
      <div>
        {user.displayName}
      </div>
    )
}
export default withStyles(useStyles)(Landing);
```